# Cordova Android app, file_not_found when trying to upload to remote server

Tags: cordova

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server using a Cordova Android application, I can resolve the URL of the file path and it I can print the path of the file so it definitely can find the file and it does exist. But whenever I go to upload the file the it keeps failing with an error code of 1 which means the file was not found.  The file is located on my sd card and I create it using the app. Here is my code for uploading the file.

```
function upload() {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        "file:///storage/emulated/0/testFile5.txt", gotFileAddress,
        error);
}

function error() {
    alert("no file");
}

function gotFileAddress(fileEntry) {
        fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
        server = encodeURI("http://test.server.com/upload");
        alert(fileURL)
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "text/plain";
        alert("a");
        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        alert("b");
        options.params = params;
        alert("c");
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(fileURL, server, win, fail, options);
        alert("d");

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            alert("upload error source " + error.source +
                " \n upload error target " + error.target);
        }
    } // end of upload
```

Has anyone any suggestions ? I have been stuck on this for ages

Comment: i know its quite old but did you fixed the issue? I am also facing the same issue.